# is there limit on cards that can be bought in shop?

Tags: clash-royale

I bought my first pekka card in 2000 and now the shop shows 9 cards and the cost is 4000.

does this mean I will get only 9 cards. or  will it refresh to 10 cards in next round?

Comment: no limit. provided you have a lot of time to spend

Answer (score 3):

The shop holds a specific number of the available cards, based on rarity. At day change (usually midnight), the cards the shop has will change, and all quantities of the new cards refresh to their max value again. You can buy all the cards in the shop, but they will not be the same tomorrow. There will be a full stock when that specific card shows up in the shop again on a future day.

Answer (score 1):

Those cards don't refresh after exhausting the card supply, you'll need to wait for the next day to get a fresh card supply.